# Lower Version DLL in NuGet Package

Tags: c#, dll, json.net, nuget

We are using the NuGet package `RestEase`.  In the `RestEases.csproj` file is the following:

```
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

We are also using `Newtonsoft.Json` in our project but have the latest version, 12.0.0.  When we install our product we include the `Newtonsoft.Json` DLL version 12.0.0 in the same location as the exe file.  When we try to run the program though, `RestEase` is trying to use version 6.0.0 and throwing this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In our project's app.config file we have a binding redirect to Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0:

Does a project binding redirect apply to the NuGet packages as well?  If so, is there a reason this one would not be properly redirected to the correct version?  If not, is there another way to resolve this version issue or do I need to also include a copy of `Newtonsoft.Json` version 6.0.0 in my installer?

Comment: I guess a binding redirect in the web/app.config should be enough, for more detailed information, please read this: https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-resolve-net-reference-and-nuget-package-version-conflicts/

Comment: @Rymo According to this site, the binding redirect I have in place should work but it is not.